# Объявление переменных в Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, переменные, синтаксис

Как объявляются переменные в Jquery (именно в jquery, а не в javascript, желательно пояснить все нюансы, включая $)?

1. var, let и const, используемые в javascript-е, допустимы в jquery?
2. кроме var, let и const что еще используется в jquery?
3. В каких случаях используется $?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> var, let и const, используемые в javascript-е, допустимы в jquery?

Да.

Хоть `var` не желательно уже использовать в новых проектах. Либо при полном понимании их особенностей по сравнению с `let` и `const`

> кроме var, let и const что еще используется в jquery?

Нет.

*Jquery* - это библиотека, которая внутри себя использует нативный *JS*, поэтому правила ровно такие же как и у просто *JS*

> В каких случаях используется $?

Моя рекомендация (и мы так делаем в компании в проектах): все переменные, относящиеся к объекту *Jquery* называл так, чтобы они начинались с `$`. Это даст понимание другим людям что, например в переменной `$users` - объект *Jquery* с пользователями, а не *js* коллекция объектов.